# Date filter is not working in my angular Controller

Tags: angularjs

For my angular app , i want to format my date. But date filter in angular is not working. My code is as follows.

```
var newDate=$filter('date')(info.list.date, 'medium');
```

where `info.list.date` is `"2014-06-25 07:22:47"`;

But for newDate I am not getting date in US-local format instead it is same as  info.list.date.

Please let me know whats wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The date filter requires the input to be a date, number, or a string conforming to ISO8601. Otherwise it just returns the original input (which is what you're seeing).

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)...

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number)
>   or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g.
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ and its shorter versions like
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is
>   specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the
>   local timezone.

In the above example, the string should be `"2014-06-25T07:22:47"`.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. But how to convert info.list.date to string/Date format then?

Comment: Where does the data come from? Either convert it at the source or you'll have to convert it yourself. If you do this a lot you can use a library like momentjs http://momentjs.com/